# How to eliminate unwanted data using not exists in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have data  like-

```
ORDER_NUMBER   REVISION_NUMBER
2-345                  1
2-345                  2
2-345                  3
5-436                  1
6-436                  1
```

Now I need to pick only those order_numbers which has only revision number 1 and that order_number should not have any other revision number like 2 ,3

In this case, it should display  order_numbers -  5-436    and 6-436  since 2-345 has revision number (2,3) also.

How do i do this in SQL?

Comment: Do you need **minimum** revision_number for each `ORDER_NUMBER` or only revision_number = 1 is accepted?

Comment: No in that case, it would select order number 2-345 too

Comment: The order numbers should have only revision number-1 .if the same order number has revision number other than 1,that order number should be eliminated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution using not exists:

```
Select ordernumber from table a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM table b 
WHERE a.ordernumber = b.ordernumber and revisionnumber != 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you say specifically you want to use `NOT EXISTS`...

```
SELECT * FROM Orders T WHERE T.REVISION_NUMBER = 1
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Orders T2 
                WHERE T2.ORDER_NUMBER = T.ORDER_NUMBER 
                AND T2.REVISION_NUMBER <> 1)
```

[Here's an SQL Fiddle that demonstrates it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ecb7c/1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select max(order_number), revision_number
from table
group by revision_number
having count(*) = 1 and revision_number = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the maximum revision for each `ORDER_NUMBER`, then filter `REVISION_NUMBER > 1`:

```
select * from 
(select ORDER_NUMBER, max(REVISION_NUMBER) as max_rev from [your_table_name] 
group by ORDER_NUMBER)
where max_rev = 1;
```

Comment: You should add an explanation on your query.